# Does Prestashop auto manages the product quantity when products are purchased?

Tags: prestashop

Sorry for asking this here, on Prestashop forum I dont get any replays. And sorry for my english.

**In order to explain my problem I will make a simple example:**

product "X product" in stock are 10 items. (quantity = 10)

when some one adds one item to card and purchase it, i think it is logically that quantity will become 9.

on my website it remains 10. Why?

---

Or at list the quantity must change when order become FINISHED/ APPROVED...

Who can give me some tips how I must configure my prestashop in order to achive the wanted result?

Answer (score 0):

Your shop may be in the mode digital product management.

Here is a possible answer. Go to your backend > Preferences > Products.

Scroll down to the end of the page. In the group of configuration 'Product stocks', make sure that you have activate the option 'Activate stock management'. It may solve your issue.

I hope it helps.